# How to add namespace to ELK cluster vi elasticsearch.yml in kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elk

im using this tutorial :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html
if i run it as is . it creates the cluster in the default namespace.
i want to create it in a custom namespace for example "my-cluster"
when running kubectl create -f elasticsearch.yml

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
  namespace: my-cluster
spec:
  version: 7.10.1
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

I'm getting error :

```
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "elasticsearch.yaml": namespaces "my-cluster" not found
```

can i even use namespace here ?

Answer (score 1):

The namespace needs to exist before you start deploying Elasticsearch. The error is complaining about the absence of `my-cluster` namespace

You can create namespace by either of below approach

1 - `kubectl create namespace my-cluster`

or

2 - `kubectl create -f ns.yaml` with content of `ns.yaml` as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
```